# Is it reasonable to install Windows 7 on my Pentium D system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, memory, cpu, motherboard

I got have this old computer containing:

- Pentium D 2.8 GHz Socket 775 CPU
- 2x512MB DDR2 memory listed at 667Hz
- An ASUS P5LD2 motherboard
- An 80GB WD HDD (expect weak specs if there are several models of that)

I'm installing both Windows and Linux on it. Linux-wise I'm going to go with Lubuntu, since it's Good Enough For Me (TM). As for Windows - I'm thinking of Windows 7, being worried about future compatibility with apps, 64-bit, etc; but I'm worried it would be too sluggish, and I might prefer XP anyway.

**Note:** This question is not about whether Windows XP is better than Windows 7 or the other way around!

Comment: Windows 7 will run fine on that PC, but with 1GB you probably do not want to run several applications at the same time).

Comment: Either accept that you're going to be obsolete, and run Win2000 which will be pretty snappy and offer all XP does .... or turn off all the graphic effects and other resource hogs in Win7 so that it behaves like Win2000.

Comment: @Debra: It goes without saying I'm going to turn off the useless junk in Windows 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by this:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/system-requirements

it looks like you might squeak by - the graphics will be a problem.

80Gb hard drive is also going to cause problems. Windows 7 is big - the 16Gb minimum quoted is not really fair. It uses so much more than that.